# Find and check td value using javascript

Tags: javascript

Adding and removing a class using jQuery is pretty easy.. like

```
$('#tblAllMessages tbody tr td:eq(6):contains(' + mySqlID + ')')
        .closest('tr').removeClass('unread')
        .addClass('read');
```

However in writing the same in javascript is cubersome. Any ideas on how to write it?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList

Comment: Why can you not use jQuery?

Comment: I can't use jQuery now. So, thats why I need to use javascript :(

Comment: @blgt In the ideal world jQuery would not be legal to use unless you know how to do the same in pure Javascript :)

Comment: @dfsq I **strongly disagree** with that. The purpose of any library (in any language) is to **abstract away** complexity, not test the library user's knowledge if its inner workings. Any *well-written* library, that is.

Comment: ... and without using the library you need the help of other developers.

Comment: To be frank yeah. As I'm not used to javascript more, I need help in this case.

Comment: If adding/removing classes is the only problem, DOM `classList` API can solve it. MDN also introduces a shim for older browsers.